# jQuery - Possible to remove input entry associated with list item?

Tags: jquery, forms, list, input

Backstory:I've created a tool to type in and press enter to add as many email addresses to a member signup as necessary. The emails are added into a scrollable div as list items with an alternating zebra stripe and a red x to the right of each email allowing the user to delete the specific email they wish to in the list.

Here's the thing: the actual inputs are hidden and separate from this list form. The list form is really just for the viewing pleasure/ease of the UX.

Question: I have successfully targeted the list item to remove that I wish to but this does not remove the input associated with the list item. How would I target this separate list item?

Here is the basic code I've created:

Targets and successfully removes the closest list item associated with the red x

```
$(".RemoveEmailBtn").live('click', function(e) {
    $(this).closest("li").fadeOut(300, function() { 
        $(this).remove();    
    });

// The additional code that is creating the list and inputs to give you a better idea of what I'm saying

} else {
    $('#Members').append('<li class="EmailList">' + email + '<span class="RemoveEmailBtn">x</span>' + '</li>');                                         
    $("li.EmailList:odd").addClass("oddItem");                     
    $('#add_email_field').append('<input class="email_inputs" type="hidden" name="emails" value="' + email + '"/>');
    $('#EmailInput').val('');
}

// The HTML as well: The HTML works perfectly. Again, the only issue is when I hit delete it only deletes the list item and not the hidden input
<div id="add_email_entry"><!-- add_email_entry -->
    <h2>Enter E-mail Addresses for New Members below:</h2>
    <div id="add_email_field"><!-- add_email_field -->
        <fieldset>
            <input class="xlarge" id="EmailInput" name="emailInput" size="30" type="text"/>
            <button id="AddEmailBtn" class="btn primary">Add</button>   
                <br/>
            <ul class="member" size="5" multiple="multiple" name="multiSelect" id="Members">
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    <!-- /add_email_field -->
</div>
<!-- /add_email_entry -->
```

Now how do I remove both the list item AND the input so when I hit the red X it removes both and not just the list item? The inputs are sticking around because I can't figure out how to target each input related to the list item I have figured out how to delete.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `HTML` will help better to answer your question.

Comment: If the HTML is there in the question we might have a clear idea of which best selectors to use.

Comment: Excellent; thank you, I will add the HTML in as reference as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to find inputs with class `.email_inputs`, and the value attribute matching the email you just removed from the list. Something like:

```
$('.email_inputs[value=user@example.com]');
```

However, it would be much simpler if you just added the hidden inputs inside the list item you create to display the email, then just removing the li would remove the input too...

Comment: That's a great idea, but if the input is appending to an entire div how does it allocate 1 input per 1 list item created? Seems, just as it had with the other div, it adds a huge trailing list with no way of saying hey code insert into that 1 specific list item and then move onto the next

Comment: I tried changing the #add_email_field to the div that the list item is in so
    
                        $('#Members li').append('<input class="email_inputs" type="hidden" name="emails" value="' + email + '"/>');

and it is duplicating all inputs into all list items. Needs some more tweaking

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What I'm suggesting is to modify your current `$('#Members').append` line, and add the hidden input HTML there, before the `</li>`.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. I think there is some confusion of the process. The hidden input HTML is added there however what is happening is each time I type in email@email.com and hit enter and add to the LI list then when I get to the 2nd, 3rd or 4th email the inputs are adding to each and every single LI instead of adding 1 per item and moving on and leaving the others alone so by the time I've created the 4th email then when you firebug each list item each one has all 4 inputs contained within it

Comment: That's because you're trying to append to `$('#Members li')`, which is all LIs inside `#Members`. You should either create the input in the same line where you create the LI, as I first suggested, or use `$('#Members li:last')` to target only the last LI you created.

Comment: Thank you bfavaretto. li:last worked like a charm. I'm a professional designer but complete jQuery newbie but I'm now required to dive in and master it and all of these view points have really helped to understand jQuery even further.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by finding the `input` element by matching its value.

```
$(".RemoveEmailBtn").live('click', function(e) {
   $(this).closest("li").fadeOut(300, function() { 
       $(this).remove(); 
       var email = $(this).find(':not(.RemoveEmailBtn)').text();   
       $('input[value="' + email + '"]').remove();
   });
});
```

Comment: I tried this and the scrollable div disappeared and entries were not permitted. Looks like it could work though .. wonder why it would be doing this? I appreciate your help